# Clean Wordpress installation shows Internal Server Error 500

Tags: apache-2.2, php, nginx, wordpress, fastcgi

I'm trying to install Wordpress installation on my dedicated server.

Copied all files, but it shows Internal Server Error 500.

Logs shows this:

```
[Wed Nov 06 18:12:36 2013] [error] [client 62.21.61.63] FastCGI: comm with server "/home/rafal/domain.com/domain.com.0fake" aborted: error parsing headers: malformed header 'HTTP/1.0 302 Found'
```

I use PHP 5.4.21 from remi repo + php_fpm_event + Apache 2.2.23 + nginxproxy 1.5.6 on CentOS 6.4 64-bit.

I've tested the same config on my test server and it worked fine. So what's wrong ?

Comment: Exactly how did you set up all of these components?

Comment: Via Kloxo-MR control panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commented:

```
cgi.rfc2616_headers = 1
```

inside php.ini and it works again ;)

Comment: Do you know ***WHY*** it works, or are you practicing [voodoo system administration](http://blog.serverfault.com/2011/06/09/press-the-green-button-twice/)? (If you don't know why, you should find out. Either way you should update your answer to explain the ***WHY*** behind the solution -- answers that are essentially "Just type this" don't help other people learn...)